# I want to display information for each technologies_id through relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship

> I have the following column in my table:

```
technologies_id[] =["2","1"]
```

> And the following relationship with technologies table:

```
public function technologies(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Technology');

}
```

> When I try to obtain information from these technologies_Id (App/project::find(1)->technologies->id). I get only for first id from my array (2)
>
> > Question: How can I get information for the second one through relationship

Answer (score 0):

The relationship you have defined on your **project** model is a one to many.  One **technology** per **project**.

You likely have your **project** model set up with the following in fillable:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'technology_id', 
    // etc.  
];
```

Your code above shows that you have then set up a **belongsTo()** method under **technologies()**.  This seems all correct, and in fact when you run your query:

```
App/project::find(1)->technologies->id
```

this produces the ONE (belongsTo) related technology because it expects a single value in the `technology_id` field.

All good... except that's not what you want, I think.  If you want to be able to pull multiple technologies for multiple projects, you probably want to re-architect your structure a little.  You are probably looking for a **[many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)**:

```
public function technologies(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Technology');
}
```

Then, when you query like before you will have many technologies for each product.  However, if you just want the ids, you will need to pull them from the *collection* of technologies:

```
App/project::find(1)->technologies->pluck('id'); // technologies is a collection
```

None of this will work, however, without the correct database structure.  To have many to many - you need a pivot table.  Laravel has a convention that it will look for in your database, or you can override that in the method for technologies.  Easiest is to just structure your database according to the convention.  A table called `project_technology` and fields for `project_id` and `technology_id`.  Remove the array from the single table field '`technology_id`' and make a new pivot table like this.  It will make life a lot easier.

Take a look at that link I put in above for how to set up the table and the convention.  Either way, hopefully this will get you where you need to go!

Comment: I have an array in my column.
I changed my relationship tobelongstomanyl but change nothing

Comment: No nothing will change if you just change the relationship.  Did you see the part about needing to change the database structure to get it to work as a many-to-many relationship?